# iPhone Circular Progress Indicator

Tags: iphone, progress-indicator, shazam

I'm trying to create a circular progress indicator like Shazam.  It will represent progress during recording.  There will be a finite amount of time and I want it to react to the sound level like Shazam's does.  Any clues where to begin?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Subclass an UIView (maybe *CircularProgress : UIView*) and draw it manually with Quartz (paths, circles, etc) on the *drawRect* method passing the % of the progress as it changes.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking of that, but I guess I'm trying to figure out how to make the radius grow as the volume increases.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar here: https://github.com/DougFischer/DFCircleActivityIndicator

You can check my code and make something more appropriated. In my scenario, I'm drawing once and then I just rotate the image/layer. You'll need to animate the strokeEnd property using something like CABasicAnimation.

This property is animated and if you increase it from 0 to 1, you'll get the "filling effect". Again, in my scenario I need the empty center, probably you won't need it, your line width will be larger.